# How to find latest entry for specific value in a dict?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries which basically follows a structure like this:

```
elements = [{'id':1, 'date':1}, {'id':1, 'date':5}, {'id':2, 'date': 6}]
```

I want to write a function that only keeps the latest dict for each duplicate `id`, based on the `date` value:

```
[{'id':1, 'date':5}, {'id':2, 'date': 6}]
```

Is there an efficient way of doing this? So far I always end up with nested for loops and conditionals and I am sure there is a pythonic solution to this...

Comment: Do they have to be dictionaries?  If you stored them as tuples with the date as the first element you could sort the list and select the 1st one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First sort the list, then create a dict with `id` as the key and the elements of the list as values.
Now you can extract the values from this list

```
>>> elements = [{'id':1, 'date':1}, {'id':1, 'date':5}, {'id':2, 'date': 6}]
>>> dct = {d['id']:d for d in sorted(elements, key=lambda d: list(d.values()))}
>>> list(dct.values())
[{'id': 1, 'date': 5}, {'id': 2, 'date': 6}]
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need nested loops. This seems reasonably straightforward:

```
elements = [{'id':1, 'date':1}, {'id':1, 'date':5}, {'id':2, 'date': 6}]
latest = {}

for ele in elements:
    if ele['id'] not in latest or ele['date'] > latest[ele['id']]['date']:
        latest[ele['id']] = ele

print(list(latest.values()))
```

This will output:

```
[{'id': 1, 'date': 5}, {'id': 2, 'date': 6}]
```

Comment: This answer is correct if "the latest dict" in the question means the dictionary with the largest value for the date field.

Comment: Yes. That seems to be the going assumption for all these answers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `itertools.groupby` to group the dicts by id, `operator.itemgetter` will be the best helper method than using a lambda *(make sure the list is sorted by `id`)*.

As for getting the "latest" I assume the last entry for each id you can use a `collections.deque` to get the last element in each group:

```
from itertools import groupby
from collections import deque
from operator import itemgetter

elements = [{'id':1, 'date':1}, {'id':1, 'date':5}, {'id':2, 'date': 6}]

get_id = itemgetter('id')
s_elements = sorted(elements, key=itemgetter('id', 'date'))
output = [deque(g, maxlen=1).pop() for _, g in groupby(s_elements, get_id)]
```

---

Output:

```
[{'id': 1, 'date': 5}, {'id': 2, 'date': 6}]
```

Comment: This answer is correct if "the latest dict" in the question means the dictionary with the largest index in the input array.

Comment: This only works if `elements` is already in date order. You need to sort by both "id" and "date"  to make it work properly (and the deque isn't needed): `[list(g)[-1] for k, g in groupby(sorted(elements, key=itemgetter('id', 'date')), itemgetter('id'))]`.

Comment: @ekhumoro Yes I edited the sort although the deque may not be needed it is slightly more efficient than using list and slicing especially if there are many items to get since the groups are iterables.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?  It turns the dicts into tuples and then sorts them.  Then when converting back to a dictionary any duplicates will be replaced by the last one.

```
def remove_duplicates(elements):
    elements_as_tuples = sorted((d['id'], d['date']) for d in elements)
    return dict(elements_as_tuples)

print(remove_duplicates(elements))

{1: 5, 2: 6}
```

The output is not in the original dictionary format but will it do?

If not you could add these steps:

```
elements_dict = remove_duplicates(elements)
list_of_dicts = [{'id': k, 'date': v} for k, v in elements_dict.items()]
print(list_of_dicts)

[{'id': 1, 'date': 5}, {'id': 2, 'date': 6}]
```